# Implement higher-order effect interpreter

Tags: haskell, haskell-polysemy

I am trying to implement the interpreter of in higher-order effect.

I have a base effect:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fplugin=Polysemy.Plugin #-}

module Hetchr.Commons.Cat where

import Polysemy
import Polysemy.Internal.Tactics

data In = In

newtype Out = Out Int
  deriving stock (Show)
  deriving newtype (Num)

data TargetE (m :: Type -> Type) (a :: Type) where
  ActA :: In -> TargetE m Out

makeSem ''TargetE

runTargetE :: InterpreterFor TargetE e
runTargetE = interpret $ \case
  ActA _ -> return $ Out 1
```

And an higher-order effect:

```hs
data ProxyE (m :: Type -> Type) (a :: Type) where
  ProxyA :: (In -> m Out) -> ProxyE m Out
  FunPA :: In -> ProxyE m Out

makeSem ''ProxyE
```

Which intends to be used as:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = print =<< runM (runTargetE $ runProxyE $ proxyA funPA)
```

I have an helper for implementation:

```hs
proxyAImpl :: Member TargetE r => (In -> Sem r Out) -> Sem r Out
proxyAImpl f = (+) <$> f In <*> actA In
```

But, I struggle with the implementation:

```hs
runProxyE :: Member TargetE r => InterpreterFor ProxyE r
runProxyE = interpretH $ \case
  ProxyA f -> do
    f' <- bindT f
    ??? proxyAImpl f'
  FunPA x -> liftT $ actA x
```

I have not found a lot  of examples, and I struggle with the types, any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if I understood correctly, you cannot create that kind of interpreters, with implementations without polymorphic types, such that I have to tweak my code to:

```hs
proxyAImpl :: (Functor f, Member TargetE r) => (In -> Sem r (f Out)) -> Sem r (f Out)
proxyAImpl f = do
  left <- f In
  right <- actA In
  return $ fmap (+ right) left

runProxyE :: Member TargetE r => InterpreterFor ProxyE r
runProxyE = interpretH $ \case
  ProxyA f -> proxyAImpl (runTSimple . f)
  FunPA x -> liftT $ actA x
```